# Can you do an or condition on a JSON using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Is it possible to do more than one condition on a JOLT transformation to create or's or and's?

I found some documentation on [If Else](https://help.digibee.com/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt) but haven't been able to apply it to what I'm trying for.  This is an if else on a single element, I need it with multiple or's.  For instance I have the following json:

```
[
  {
    "alpha": "a",
    "beta": "b",
    "omega": "o",
    "exists": true,
    "description": "goodbye world"
  },
  {
    "alpha": "1",
    "beta": "2",
    "omega": "3",
    "exists": false,
    "description": "hello world"
  },
  {
    "alpha": "z",
    "beta": "x",
    "omega": "y",
    "exists": true,
    "description": "hello mars"
  }
]
```

I need to figure out a JOLT that can look at the entire array and say "if Exists is True or description is hello world"  So it outputs:

```
[
  {
    "alpha": "a",
    "beta": "b",
    "omega": "o",
    "exists": true,
    "description": "goodbye world"
  },
  {
    "alpha": "1",
    "beta": "2",
    "omega": "3",
    "exists": false,
    "description": "hello world"
  },
  {
    "alpha": "z",
    "beta": "x",
    "omega": "y",
    "exists": true,
    "description": "hello mars"
  }
]
```

Jolt to find hello world:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "description": {
          "hello world": null,
          "*": {
            "@2": "&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I know how jolt for for the if exists and the filter or description piece but how do I put them together to work in unison like an or clause such as:
if(("exists" == "true") | ("description" == "hello world"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think of the below solution which I seem to make it work with one shift unless I'm missing something.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "exists": {
          "true": {
            "@(2)": "[]"
          },
          "*": {
            "@(2,description)": {
              "hello world": {
                "@(4)": "[]"
              }
            }
          } /**/
        }
      }
    }
 }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: This works too, and a bit cleaner.

Comment: Yes, this one is better @rsnyder

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a new attribute by concatenating those values(`true` and `hello world`), and then check out for the existence by your conditional checking method such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ed": "=concat(@(1,exists),@(1,description))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ed": {
          "true*|*hello world": { // | stands for OR
                                  // check out the value of "ed" whether
                                  // starts with "true" OR ends with "hello world"
            "@2": "" // replicate the whole value from the "ed"'s level
                     // without any object key(eg. "") 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rd of the lately generated attribute
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ed": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I would have never thought of this concept.